# How to run knex in electron's preload js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, knex.js

I'm trying to load `knex` in the **preload js** script instead of in the **Main Process**

i have though of importing *knex* from **Main Process** using `module.exports` you get new errors

> /home/alexander/Deve…enderer/init.js:166 Unable to load preload
>   script: /home/alexander/Develop/Electron/App/app/preload.js
>
> /home/alexander/Deve…enderer/init.js:167 TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'on' of undefined

**When i add this in preload:**

```
//preload js

var knex = require("knex")({
    client: "sqlite3",
    connection: {
        filename: path.join(__dirname, './database.sqlite')
    },
     useNullAsDefault: true
});
```

**I end up with these errors in the electrons app devtools**

> /home/alexander/Deve…enderer/init.js:166 Unable to load preload
>   script: /home/alexander/Develop/Electron/App/app/preload.js
>
> /home/alexander/Deve…enderer/init.js:167 ReferenceError: path is not defined 
>   (anonymous)    @   /home/alexander/Deve…enderer/init.js:167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
```

you use `path` 
so try

```
//preload js
// added path
const path = require("path");

var knex = require("knex")({
    client: "sqlite3",
    connection: {
        filename: path.join(__dirname, './database.sqlite')
    },
     useNullAsDefault: true
});
```

Comment: yes right how'd miss that...i debbugged that for like 3 hours...feels rather stupid